# sed string with special character New

Tags: linux, sed, special-characters

when i use this script to replace :

```
mrm.fr.mycompany.com by 10.70.89.40:8081/artifactory


sed -i -e "s/mrm.fr.mycompany.com/10.70.89.40:8081/artifactory/g" config.xml
```

i have the error :

```
 sed: -e expression nÂ°1, caractÃ¨re 41: option inconnue pour `s'
```

can anyone help me
thanks in advance

regard,
Youssef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape `/` with `\`:

```
sed -i 's/mrm.fr.mycompany.com/10.70.89.40:8081\/artifactory/' config.xml
```

Or use this:

```
sed -i 's|mrm.fr.mycompany.com|10.70.89.40:8081/artifactory|' config.xml
```